# Is there a component like terminal block that would allow you to create a power rail?

Tags: components, low-power

I'm after supplying 5v to a bunch (5) devices from a single 5v power supply (with sufficient power output). I'm wondering, is there something like a terminal block, but instead of being  pairs of connections, all of one side would be connected and all of the other, so you could wire in your +5v and GND to the end and effectively have a power rail that you could wire in to.

Comment: Something like this? https://media.perfprotech.com/media/products/lns-2012/images-large/S/Seachoice/50-13531.jpg  Or this? http://www.texasindustrialelectric.com/images/bs_2702_sm.gif

Comment: You can always use single pins/terminals and connect them on the pcb together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few here: https://www.perfprotech.com/terminal-blocks-bus-bars/category/5492

I can't vouch for the site, and I'm not sure I would recommend buying from them, but yes -- the parts you describe do exist.

It appears the "DualBus" product line is made by Blue Sea Systems (if I'm understanding correctly). Perhaps that's an option you would like to pursue?

Comment: Perfect! "Bus Bar" is the information I was after.

Comment: Glad to help! =)

Answer (score -1):

After re-reading your question, this in not what you are looking for.

I think a Diode Array is what you are looking for, there are a lot to chose from on Digi-key, for example [Link](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1SS308(TE85L,F/1SS308(TE85LFTR-ND/4304995)

Comment: How is that a bus terminal block??

Comment: Can't delete my answer, sorry for the confusion, please ignore it.

Comment: Understood. Happens to the best of us =P

Comment: ok, thanks for your input though.